# Is there a simple way to animate several points in the same plot with FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I was trying to do an animation for fun using the mathematical solution for the pendulum. I know that my script is a little bit messy but I would really hope to improve. Below is my attempt to produce an animation using FuncAnimation from Matplotlib. I generated the data information for 3 points but my gif only shows one.

I read the documentation examples and some answers here similar to my problem but I really did not understand how to apply a simple solution in my case. I also saw that it was possible to use a scatter plot for this case but still I was not able to do it.

I would be grateful if you could recommend me a solution considering that I am a newbie using Python. And any other recommendation regarding the script will be kindly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib inline

def solution(g, length, n, initial_angle, initial_velocity):
#     g = 9.81
#     l = 9.81
#     n = 8
    
    def model(u, t):
        return (u[1], - (g / length) * np.sin(u[0] * np.pi / 180))
    
    # Initial angle, and initial velocity
    theta0 = [initial_angle, initial_velocity]

    # Desired time interval
    time = np.arange(0, 2 * n * np.pi, 0.1)

    solution = odeint(model, theta0, time)
    return solution[:,0]

data = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    data.append(solution(9.81, 9.81 * i / 3, n, -17.5, 0))
    
data = np.array(data)
x_temp = np.sin(data * np.pi / 180)
y_temp = - np.cos(data * np.pi / 180)

# Coordinates for 3 pendulums
for i in range(0, 3):
    x_temp[i] = (9.81 * i / 3) * x_temp[i]
    y_temp[i] = (9.81 * i / 3) * y_temp[i]

# minimums and maximums based on the longest pendulum
x_min = x_temp[2].min()
x_max = x_temp[2].max()
y_min = y_temp[2].min()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(x_min - 0.5, x_max + 0.5), ylim=(y_min - 0.5, 0))

point, = ax.plot([],[], 'go', lw=3)

# def init():
#     point.set_data([], [])
#     return point,

def animation_frames(i, x, y):
#     point.set_data(x, y)
    for j in range(0,3):
        point.set_data(x[j][i], y[j][i])
    
    return point,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animation_frames, frames=len(x_temp[0]), fargs=(x_temp, y_temp), interval=10)

animation.save('simple_pendulum.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

---

**Edit**

I generated a simple case as recommended. The lists to be used just before calling the sublopts function are:

```
x_tem, y_temp

(array([[-0.98330796, -0.97717458, -0.95882857, -0.92843441, -0.88627296,
         -0.83275034, -0.76840839, -0.69393471, -0.61017043, -0.51811348,
         -0.41891573, -0.31387291, -0.20440652],
        [-1.96661593, -1.9604803 , -1.94210039, -1.91155767, -1.86898966,
         -1.81459239, -1.74862365, -1.67140657, -1.58333345, -1.48486936,
         -1.37655514, -1.25900948, -1.13292978],
        [-2.94992389, -2.94378752, -2.92539636, -2.89480454, -2.85210308,
         -2.79742099, -2.73092681, -2.65283041, -2.56338497, -2.46288906,
         -2.35168869, -2.23017916, -2.0988066 ]]),
 array([[-3.11865443, -3.12058165, -3.12626739, -3.13542813, -3.14760548,
         -3.16218704, -3.17843492, -3.19552102, -3.21256783, -3.22869299,
         -3.2430556 , -3.2549015 , -3.26360506],
        [-6.23730886, -6.2392401 , -6.24498567, -6.25440223, -6.26725439,
         -6.28322007, -6.30189776, -6.32281583, -6.34544365, -6.36920427,
         -6.39348856, -6.41767054, -6.44112336],
        [-9.35596329, -9.35789587, -9.36366147, -9.37316418, -9.38624568,
         -9.40268769, -9.42221517, -9.44450056, -9.46916879, -9.49580315,
         -9.52395193, -9.55313566, -9.58285505]]))
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I added the lists as you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your goal is but I tried to imitate your example of animating three points independently as close as possible. I only added different color and marker features, so that the points can be better distinguished:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    
n=100
x_temp = [np.linspace(-10, -8, n),
          np.linspace(-9, -6, n),
          np.linspace(-6, -10, n)]
y_temp = [np.sin(x_temp[0]),
          np.cos(x_temp[1]),
          np.sin(x_temp[2])]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-11, -5), ylim=(- 1.5, 1.5))

points = []
for j, (col, mar) in enumerate(zip(["green", "blue", "red"], ["o", "x", "s"])):
    newpoint, = ax.plot(x_temp[j][0], y_temp[j][0], color=col, marker=mar)
    points.append(newpoint)

def animation_frames(i):
    for j in range(0,3):
        points[j].set_data(x_temp[j][i], y_temp[j][i])        


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animation_frames, frames=len(x_temp[0]), interval=30)
    
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just trying to animate the movement of a single pendulum, but the I thought that seeing the patterns due to their length differences would be more interesting. Maybe there is another more efficient way to do this than the one I was trying to do.

Comment: This example is definitely able to do what you are trying to achieve. Just calculate the x and y values for each pendulum and store them in their x_temp, y_temp sublist. The rest of the animation is more or less ready to go. Have fun exploring matplotlib animations and physics.